# "Questionnaire" referenced before the assignment in Tkinter format

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted to make separate question which it wouldn't deviate from the original thread (given the downvotes it had due to my lack of attention to forum rules)

For some odd reason, I had made a new window called `Questionnaire`:

```
def Questionnaire():
      quiz_page = Tk()
      quiz_page.title('Questionnaire')
      quiz_page.geometry('600x350')
      greet = Label(quiz_page, text='Welcome to the questionnaire! You will '
                                    'answer a few questions to produce a result '
                                    'for both you and your teacher to see!')
      greet.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

Which I then called the function to the student login page.

```
def student_menu():
      #student_login.destroy()
      student_page = Tk()
      student_page.title('Hello student')
      student_page.geometry('300x130')
      Welcome_msg = Label(student_page, text='Welcome').pack()
      Questionnaire = Button(student_page,text='Quiz',command=Questionnaire).pack()
      View = Button(student_page,text='View',command=view).pack()
```

But when I login the app, I get a window with no buttons and this error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hassan Nur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan Nur\Documents\Python - Programming Project\Project\Python Project\Python Project.py", line 78, in student_confirm
    student_menu()
  File "C:\Users\Hassan Nur\Documents\Python - Programming Project\Project\Python Project\Python Project.py", line 107, in student_menu
    Questionnaire = Button(student_page,text='Quiz',command=Questionnaire).pack()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Questionnaire' referenced before assignment
```

If possible (or even eligible) could you please help?

Comment: You can't have `Questionnaire` as both the name of a function and the name of a button.  Change one of them.

Comment: Tkinter applications shouldn't call `Tk()` more than once. If you need multiple independent windows, call [`tkinter.Toplevel()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html) to create them.

Comment: With regards to the error shown in your question: You're getting the exception because `Questionnaire` is a local variable in the `student_menu()` function, so when the line creating the `Button` is executed, the `command=Questionnaire` portion refers to that variable, _not_ to the class with exactly the same name that you've defined.

Comment: @jasonharper It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to martineau and jasonharper!
Found out that Questionnaire was already defined as a button which as you can see...

```
def student_menu():
  #student_login.destroy()
  student_page = Tk()
  student_page.title('Hello student')
  student_page.geometry('300x130')
  Welcome_msg = Label(student_page, text='Welcome').pack()
  Question = Button(student_page,text='Quiz',command=Questionnaire).pack()
  View = Button(student_page,text='View',command=view).pack()
```

I simply had to rename one of the buttons